# Trying to write form contents to a text file but only getting nonsense

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, webforms

I'm trying to write to a text file the contents submitted from this form, but I'm not succeeding, and I keep getting weird output such as a string of blank spaces, etc.

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['url_submit'];
$fh = fopen('info.txt', 'a');
if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX)) {
    fwrite($fh, $data . "\n");
    fflush($fh);
    flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
} else {
    trigger_error("failed to lock file");
}
fclose($fh);
?>    

<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" onSubmit="return validateURL()" id="url_submit" name="url_submit">
<input type="text" autofocus="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" style="width: 600px;margin-left: -11%;" value="" name="url">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of your input is url not url_submit.

```
$data = $_POST['url'];
```

What does your javascript function validateURL() do?

Comment: darn..the file is empty. didn't work. This stuff is always harder than it should be

Comment: What is onSubmit="return validateURL()" doing?  Try remove that.